# Setting default values in XSLT stylesheet

Tags: json, xml, xslt, icecast

I have a json.xsl file for Icecast2 stream that looks something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/icestats"><!-- <xsl:param name="callback" /> <xsl:value-of select="$callback" /> -->parseMusic({<xsl:for-each select="source">
  "<xsl:value-of select="@mount"/>":
  {
  "title":"<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:value-of select="artist" /> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" />"
  }
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>});
</xsl:template>
```

Which works fine but whenever the stream goes off and doesn't receive any metadata the "title" just says "":

```
parseMusic({
"/listen.mp3":
{
"title":"",
}
});
```

How do I set a default value (e.g. "title":"will be back soon") in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:value-of select="(title, 'will be back soon')[1]"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, use `xsl:choose`.